# Using before or after save in parse cloud code to add a userId to another table

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am making a running app and would like to add the `username` and `userId` to another Class along with the `User` Class as soon as they register. I am having difficulty with the `userId` not saving to the `Runner` Class, the `username` saves just fine. Is this because I am using the code in the `beforeSave` function? How would I go about fixing this?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
// Check if the User is newly created

if (request.object.isNew()) {
    // Set default values


var RunnerClass =  Parse.Object.extend("Runner");
var runner =  new RunnerClass;
runner.set("username", request.object.get("username"));
runner.set("userId", request.object.id);



runner.save(null,{
success:function(runner) { 
response.success(runner);
},
error:function(error) {
response.error(error);
 }
});

}
response.success();


});
```

If relevant this is for iOS.

I attempted to user the afterSave but nothing gets added into the Runner class only the User class

I used the following code :

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
// Check if the User is newly created

if (!request.object.existed()) {
    // Set default values


var RunnerClass =  Parse.Object.extend("Runner");
var runner =  new RunnerClass;
runner.set("username", request.object.get("username"));
runner.set("userId", request.object.id);


runner.save()

}



  });
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `beforeSave` handler a new object will not have an id yet, so the `userId` of the `RunnerClass` will not have a value.

You can use the `afterSave` handler and create the `RunnerClass` there. In an `afterSave` handler, you can use `request.object.existed()` instead of `request.object.isNew()`. Immediately after the first time an object is saved, `existed()` will return false to indicate that the last server operation created the object. If the object is subsequently saved again, the object will have already existed on the server, so `existed()` will return true from then on.

**UPDATE**

I have tested your afterSave function on my own Parse Service and it works well. It creates a Runner class with correct userId and username. This is the exact code that I used

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("_User", function(request, response) {

    if (!request.object.existed()) {
        // Set default values

        console.log("User did not yet exist")

        var RunnerClass =  Parse.Object.extend("Runner");
        var runner =  new RunnerClass;
        runner.set("username", request.object.get("username"));
        runner.set("userId", request.object.id);
        runner.save()

    } else {
        console.log("User exists")
    }
})
```

Comment: I attempted the afterSave but nothing saved into the RunnerClass, any other ideas?

Comment: You can add some console.log() statements to your code to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: @AlexKoren I shared the code when I edited my original question statement

Comment: @PeterFennema  I am not that good with cloud code only starting to get familiarized with it where would I add the console.log()?

Comment: You use it in a way similar to a swift print() statement, anywhere you like. You can view the runtime output in the Parse dashboard logs. I would add console.log("Will create RunnerClass") just before the line where you create the Runnerclass, to check if this code is reached at all. And you can log values of variables, like console.log(request.object.id). Hope this helps.

Comment: @PeterFennema I placed the console.log("Will create RunnerClass") as well as one for each variable and nothing appeared in Xcode

Comment: The logs will appear in the dashboard of Parse, not in Xcode.

Comment: I suddenly have another idea: Replace Parse.User by "_User"

Comment: I checked the logs and received an error of Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'error' of undefined
    at Object.runner.save.error (main.js:66:14)

Comment: @PeterFennema I have tried the _User and they both retrieve the username when I console log it but for some reason it just doesn't get input into the Runner Class